# Python -- A base class calling subclass instance variables

Tags: python

This is my code. It has a base class that has a subclass that from the baseclass accesses subclass fields.

```
>>> g = Base()
>>> gg = ExtendBase()
>>> for i in g:
...     print i.identification
... 
Base
```

it's suppose to print ExtendBase then Base. Why is this not working?
I don't know if this is a form of polymorphism accessing fields of a subclass from a baseclass???

```
class Base(object):
    Trackable = []
    def __init__(self, ):
        self.identification = 'Base'
        Base.Trackable.append(self)
        self.trackable = list(Base.Trackable)
    def __len__(self, ):
        return len(Base.Trackable)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return Base.Trackable[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        Base.Trackable[key] = value
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del Base.Trackable[key]
    def __iter__(self, ):
        return self
    def next(self, ):
        if self.noMoreToGo():
            self.trackable = list(Base.Trackable)
            raise StopIteration
        for item in Base.Trackable:
            if item.identification == 'ExtendBase':
                self.trackable.remove(item)
                return item
            if item.identification == 'Base':
                self.trackable.remove(item)
                return item
    def noMoreToGo(self, ):
        if self.trackable:
            return False
        else:
            return True


class ExtendBase(Base):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(ExtendBase, self).__init__()
        self.identification = 'ExtendBase'
```

Comment: You've got an instance of Base, so why do you expect it to know anything about ExtendBase? If you run this for `gg` which is an instance of ExtendBase, you should get "ExtendBase" when printing the id.

Comment: Your `__iter__` and `next` don't make sense, especially `next`. Also, why would you expect `ExtendBase` before `Base` when the `ExtendBase` instance is created second?

Comment: Why do you have `self.trackable`? Heck, most of this code is unuseful or wrong. `self.trackable` and everything related to implementing the iterator or sequence protocols should just be removed; if you want to iterate over all tracked objects, iterate over `Base.Trackable`.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with the `identification` field. It's all the incorrect attempt to implement iteration.

Comment: Smells like an x-y situation. Rather than asking about difficulties with your implementation, what is the actual real problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

**g** is an instance of **Base**; it is not an iterable of all objects of the class, and does not contain references to any element of a subclass.

g.identification is, "Base", as you expect, and gg.identification is "ExtendBase".  I think your problem is in thinking that **g** somehow represents all objects of the base class or any subclass.

Comment: `Base.Trackable` *is* a list of all instances of the base class, and the intent is for an instance of `g` to be an iterator for that list. The implementation is a bit wrong, though.